# Tensors of type $(r,s)$ in relation to tensor algebra $T(V)$

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, direct-sum, dual-spaces

According to the following blog-post, https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/tensor-bundles/

The vector space $V$ and its dual $V*$ are combined to form the “tensors of type $(r,s)$”:

> $\displaystyle T^r_s(V)=V\otimes\dots\otimes V\otimes V^*\otimes\dots\otimes V^*$

I'm curious as to whether there exists a relationship between $T^r_s(V)$ and the tensor algebra $T(V)$ (or $k$-th tensor power $T^k{V}$).

The wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra defines the tensor algebra as follows:

> $T(V)= \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty T^kV = K\oplus V \oplus (V\otimes V) \oplus (V\otimes V\otimes V) \oplus \cdots.$

Following the previous trends of direct sum, do any relationships like these exist:

$T^k(V)=\bigoplus_{r+s=k}^k T^r_s(V)$

and,

$T(V)=\bigoplus_{r,s=0}^\infty T^r_s(V)$, with $r,s\in\mathbb{N_0}$

Any additional clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The tensor algebra only sees tensor powers of $V$, not $V^*$. When we write the tensor algebra as a direct sum of terms $T^k(V)$ these pieces are just the $T_0^k(V)$ terms in your other notation.

Comment: I see. I realised just after I posted tye question that the tensor algebra T(V) doesn't actually contain any copies of the dual V*. @Nate So what you're saying is that only (k,0)-tensors "exist" in the tensor algebra if we were to think about their valence?

Comment: Yea only the $(k,0)$ tensors exist in the tensor algebra.  One can also look at the direct sum of all the $T_s^r(V)$ spaces, which also has the structure of an algebra but as far as I know that doesn't have a name (it is $T(V)\otimes T(V^*)$ though).